# How to store a list of values from mongo subdocument

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection with documents like this

```
  {
"_id" : ObjectId("59de9454e4b03289d79eeab4"),
"type" : "Draft",
.
.
.
headers
{
"payload" : [ 
{
"_id" : "ABC",
},
{
"_id" :"DEF",
}]
```

how should i store the _Id values in a variable like

```
result: ["ABC","DEF"]
```

I tried a query like this, but is not working

```
var result = []
db.request.find({"_id" : ObjectId("59de9454e4b03289d79eeab4")}).forEach(function(u) { result.push(u.headers.payload._id) })
```

Comment: Use [`.distinct()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/). `db.request.distinct("headers.payload._id")` if all you need is a "unique" array or expect it to be unique. Your attempt does not work because the values are within an array in the documents themselves. It's easy to correct, but using `.distinct()` is even easier still if that is all you really need.

Comment: This works fine otherwise, but the challenge in my case is that i need "payload._id " values in the array, only if "payload.status" is "XYZ". 
Not sure if distinct can handle that @NeilLunn

Comment: Your question makes no mention of "payload.status". As such it's really a different question and really should be asked "clearly" in a completely new question. But look for answers first. Because what you appear to be asking is something I would be certain I have submitted an answer to here before already.

Answer (score 0):

Your input doc is a tad malformed but if `payload` is a single field subfield of `headers` i.e. it is not an array, and you want to do a `$match` or otherwise filter the material before you extract the `_id` values and you want all the `_id` values (not a distinct set) and returned neatly in a field called `result` then this does the trick:

```
db.foo.aggregate([
{$match: {"_id": 1}}
,{$project: {result: {$map: {
                 input: "$headers.payload",
                 as: "z",
                 in: "$$z._id"
        }}
}}
            ]);
```